# MonoGame mouse button status changes when other button is pressed

Tags: c#, xna, mouse, monogame

I am trying to print the status of the two mouse buttons, in the Update method.

```
 MouseState state = Mouse.GetState();
 Console.WriteLine(state.LeftButton + " " + state.RightButton);
```

Then, when I click left, I get

```
 Pressed   Released
```

If I maintain the left, but now click the right, during about one second, the left button is "released" and gets back to "pressed" in a while

Any idea if there is any known bug on this, or any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bug. If you hold left button pressed and press right button. Behaviour of left button will be pressed, released, pressed.

It is easy to test it in your browser.

```
1- Press your left button.
```

Left Button behavior : `pressed`

```
2- Press your right button.
```

Left Button behavior : `released`

```
3- In your browser you will see menu items. Bring your cursor to one of them.
```

Left Button behavior : `pressed`

```
4- Release your left button.
```

Left Button behavior : `released`

Result : You will see that you clicked.

Comment: So, you are saying it is a problem on the way mouse works globally, and not specific of MonoGame/XNA. Damn!